# Total Order in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

What would be an elegant way to represent an arbitrary [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) between elements of a list in Python, e.g. the function *torder* in the following example (where C>B>A). **Edit:** I assume the list defines the order:

```
>>> s = ['A','B','C']
>>> torder('B')
['A']
>>> torder('C')
['A','B']
```

I could do that using *if* and *elif* if the list is short but was looking for something more pythonic.

Comment: Note that `ord` is a built in function: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord. It might not be a good idea to call your function the same name.

Comment: What do you use the function for? The most common interface for defining an order is either a comparator function, or if your set is order-isomorphic to a subset of the integers/floats/strings/tuples, then you use a "key" function. The latter is strongly preferred for sorting. I would not consider "a function that returns a list containing all elements less than its argument" to be an elegant way of representing an order no matter how that function is implemented, unless you're using the order in a very specific way that means you never need pair-wise comparisons.

Comment: @SteveJessop imagine a list of predators, if I am 'C' and want to know who I can eat, this function is useful. The objects have to be arbitrary, but I don't want to use classes. Turning the list output into a boolean or an integer like a comparator is of course possible, and pairwise comparisons can use the length of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def orde(i, s):
    t = sorted(s)
    return t[:t.index(i)]

s = ['A','B','C']
orde("B", s)
```

Comment: Very nice! I used ['A','B','C'] as examples only and assumed the list was already sorted, but the brevity of return t[:t.index(i)] is great.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools
itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'C', s)
```

If order is not defined by the position in the list:

```
sorted(filter(lambda x: x < 'C', s))
```

Comment: This assumes that the input is sorted.

Comment: @Tichodroma: I thought the list defines the order.. oh well, let's hope next time he gives a good example.

Comment: Yes, it does: `list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != 'Z', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Z', 'X', 'Y']))` results in `['A', 'B', 'C']`, not `['A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'Y']`.

Comment: @yi_H yes, I assumed the list defined the order